# Malformed Lines when Updating

Tags: 14.04, software-center

I am getting this error code

```
E: Malformed line 7 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d canonical_partner.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I went to the lines in the 2 malformed lines via gedit and saw this... What's wrong?

[image: Line 7-NOT the highlighted one as pointed out it is further down]

I have no clue what it means when it says the list of sources could not be read... I assume that is explaining the errors with the malformed lines.

**EDIT** Found the issue with the line one however it still has a problem with the line 7:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
```

Comment: Try to insert a space before "trusty"

Comment: In your second case, it looks to me like you've highlighted line 4 not line 7 (your text editor is wrapping long lines). Really, it's best to post text rather than screenshots.

Comment: Please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images (see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](/q/420981/175814)).

Comment: cmks solved the line 1 problem however the line 7 has a different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 7 needs "trusty" in it, like this:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```